# Contenteditable div cursor outside of div

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have a div that has the attribute `contenteditable="true"` it works, but chrome (Ubuntu 14.04) places the cursor outside of the div as seen in this image:

[image: Div]

Why is it doing that? I am using this html (with smarty):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-control" contenteditable="true" id="tags">
        <div contenteditable="false" class="tag">one <a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></div>
        <div contenteditable="false" class="tag">two <a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using this for the css:

```
.tag{
    background-color: #01b6ef;
    color: #012935;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.tag a{
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.tag a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Is this a chrome bug, or is this something I can fix, and how?

http://jsfiddle.net/y3ms3f7a/1/

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.04: http://jsfiddle.net/y3ms3f7a/1/

Comment: must be a bootstrap bug, because I mostly just added bootstrap, which is almost the only difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding an `input-group` to the form control, like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-control" contenteditable="true" id="tags">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div contenteditable="false" class="tag">one <a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></div>
            <div contenteditable="false" class="tag">two <a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y3ms3f7a/5/

Comment: what style properties does `input-group` have

Comment: That is a bootstrap class